# Python - comparing 2 data frames

Tags: python, data-mining, dataframe

I have a large dataset, for an idea please see below.

Each row has a sender, receiver, and message. There can be multiple columns for messages. It has indexes.

| sdr | rcr | msg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | msg_a |
| A | B | msg_b |
| A | B | msg_c |
| A | C | msg_a |
| A | C | msg_b |
| A | C | msg_c |
| C | A | msg_a |
| B | A | msg_a |
| C | A | msg_b |
| C | A | msg_c |
| B | A | msg_a |
| B | A | msg_b |

1. Sender A sends 3 messages to B and 3 to C.
2. If you notice, C communicates back, though, in a different order.
3. B message's back but sends 2 responses for msg_a.
4. B's response to A for msg_c is missing.

The expected output (with indexes):

| sdr | rcr | msg | msg_rcr_idx | idx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | msg_a | 7, 10 | 0 |
| A | B | msg_b | 11 | 1 |
| A | B | msg_c | NaN | 2 |
| A | C | msg_a | 6 | 3 |
| A | C | msg_b | 8 | 4 |
| A | C | msg_c | 9 | 5 |
| C | A | msg_a | 3 | 6 |
| B | A | msg_a | 0 | 7 |
| C | A | msg_b | 4 | 8 |
| C | A | msg_c | 5 | 9 |
| B | A | msg_a | 0 | 10 |
| B | A | msg_b | 1 | 11 |

How do I achieve this?

**What I have done:**
I thought dividing the df into df groups of sdr and rcr would be good to start with.

sdr_dir_rcr is a column that has concatenated sdr-rcr.

```
groups = df.groupby(df.sdr_dir_rcr) // grouping by concatenated column

group_A_B = all_groups.get_group('A_B') // pulling values in group A_B (in same order) 

group_B_A = all_groups.get_group('B_A') // pulling values in group B_A (in same order)
```

Above divides my dataset in multiple groups.

group_A_B =

```
    sdr rcr msg
0   A  B  msg_a
1   A  B  msg_b
2   A  B  msg_c
```

group_B_A =

```
    sdr rcr msg
7    B  A  msg_a
10   B  A  msg_a
11   B  A  msg_b
```

How to utilize this to get the expected output?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a programming question than a data science question and would therefore be better suited for stackoverflow, but the following is already quite close to what you're looking for:

```py
(
    df
    .merge(df.reset_index(), how="left", left_on=["rcr", "msg"], right_on=["sdr", "msg"], suffixes=("", "_"))
    .groupby(["sdr", "rcr", "msg"])["index"]
    # concatenate indices, only use unique indices and sort them first
    .agg(lambda x: ", ".join([str(i) for i in sorted(set(x)) if i != 0]))
    .reset_index()
)
```

```
   sdr rcr    msg      index
0    A   B  msg_a  7.0, 10.0
1    A   B  msg_b       11.0
2    A   B  msg_c        nan
3    A   C  msg_a        6.0
4    A   C  msg_b        8.0
5    A   C  msg_c        9.0
6    B   A  msg_a        3.0
7    B   A  msg_b   1.0, 4.0
8    C   A  msg_a        3.0
9    C   A  msg_b   1.0, 4.0
10   C   A  msg_c   2.0, 5.0
```

Comment: Thanks Oxbowerce for your answer. I will be careful next time. I keep getting nulls in the index column. No errors. Is there something I am missing?